# What is the problem with the GSM 590e module?

Tags: gsm

I have a M590e GSM module (assembled from a kit)

it is this kit in this link

http://www.laser-shop.eu/arduino-platform/1277-arduino-gsm-gprs-module-m590e-900m-1800m-kit-1460408201.html

I have sucessfully interfaced he module a PC and it does recognise AT commands sent through the serial port.
When the module starts up (with sim inserted) it does NOT say PBREADY. After waiting a few minutes after startup.

I type in the command (with the sim inserted of course)

AT+CREG

I get the response

0,2

which I think means it is searching for a network.
When I take the sim card out of its holder and measure the voltage pins that supply power to the sim card (the VCC,GND pins in the sim card holder) I get a reading of 0.01v with a multimeter-is this normal?-should it be at least 1.8v here?-does the voltage increase in specific circumstances when the sim is inserted? 
Im not sure, but is my module faulty?
I cant figure out what the fault is. I have been unable to connect any sim to a UK network so far-and I have tried three different sim card (all known to be working from testing in a phone).

Comment: Does your SIM have a pin code check enabled? Are you sure you're measuring the voltage right (between C1 and C5, not touching anything else with the probes)?

Answer (score 1):

This module is pulling a lot of power. I had to use a 5v/1500mA powersupply, but also I had to add a big capacitor also! I soldered a 2200µF at the input of the GSM m590 module. And don't forget to put the "BOOT" pin on ground.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at https://cdn.instructables.com/ORIG/FX6/UAHQ/IZ6CYGIU/FX6UAHQIZ6CYGIU.pdf
I think the 2 is "The registration is refused". Not sure if it means you have an usable SIM. 3 is "not registered, the terminal is searching base stations"